# Can I convert an incoming stream of data into an array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming

I'm trying to learn streaming data and manipulating it with the telecom churn dataset provided [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EricChiang/churn/master/data/churn.csv). I've written a method to calculate this in batch:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{SVMModel, SVMWithSGD, LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
object batchChurn{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //setting spark context
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("churn")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    //loading and mapping data into RDD
    val csv = sc.textFile("file://filename.csv")
    val data = csv.map {line =>
    val parts = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val stringvec = Array(parts(1)) ++ parts.slice(4,20)
    val label = parts(20).toDouble
    val vec = stringvec.map(_.toDouble)
    LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(vec))
    }
    val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7,0.3))
    val (training, testing) = (splits(0),splits(1))
    val numClasses = 2
    val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
    val numTrees = 6
    val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto"
    val impurity = "gini"
    val maxDepth = 7
    val maxBins = 32
    val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
    val labelAndPreds = testing.map {point =>
        val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
        (point.label, prediction)
}
}
}
```

I've had no problems with this. Now, I looked at the NetworkWordCount example provided on the spark website, and changed the code slightly to see how it would behave.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 9999)

val data = lines.flatMap(_.split(","))
```

My question is: is it possible to convert this DStream to an array which I can input into my analysis code? Currently when I try to convert to Array using `val data = lines.flatMap(_.split(","))`, it clearly says that:`error: value toArray is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put all the elements of a `DStream` in an array because those elements will keep being read over the wire, and your array would have to be indefinitely extensible.

The adaptation of this decision tree model to a streaming mode, where training and testing data arrives continuously, is not trivial for algorithmical reasons — while the answers mentioning collect are technically correct, they're not the appropriate solution to what you're trying to do.

If you want to run decision trees on a Stream in Spark, you may want to look at [Hoeffding trees](https://huawei-noah.github.io/streamDM/docs/HDT.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your DStream contains many RDDs you can get access to the RDDs using `foreachRDD` function.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.html#foreachRDD(scala.Function1)

then each RDD can be converted to array using `collect` function.

this has already been shown here

[For each RDD in a DStream how do I convert this to an array or some other typical Java data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772799/for-each-rdd-in-a-dstream-how-do-i-convert-this-to-an-array-or-some-other-typica)

Answer (score 1):

DStream.foreachRDD gives you an RDD[String] for each interval of 
course, you could collect in an array

```
  val arr = new ArrayBuffer[String]();
   data.foreachRDD {
    arr ++= _.collect() 

}
```

Also keep in mind you could end up having way more data than you want in your driver since a DStream can be huge.

To limit the data for your analysis , I would do this way

```
data.slice(new Time(fromMillis), new Time(toMillis)).flatMap(_.collect()).toSet
```